# Sci-fi book and TV series: teenage clones on a spaceship ark, remembering their original lives

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a story as I would like to read it again but cannot remember the title.

Synopsis: a group of teenagers are on a spaceship, all are clones but don't know this due to some process (I think their skin pigmentation has been altered). Their minds individually travel back in time to remember their original lives. They're traveling around space in a gigantic Ark but don't know it's an ark initially. They are attacked by creatures created by the computer system that raised them (I think the computer is called COL but I could be wrong). They eventually make it to Mars to repopulate, only to find they are not needed or wanted there, so they carry on to Earth to repopulate this with life. I believe it was made into a TV series by [Channel 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_5_%28UK%29) (UK) back when they first began as a TV station.

Comment: Your channel 5 and my channel 5 are going to be different.  What country and what network are you talking about?  Any idea what year you may have read the book/story?  Was it a novel or a short story?

Comment: Channel 5 in the UK is literally called "Channel 5" - they also have Channel 4

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178614/looking-for-a-novel-with-a-ship-crewed-only-by-children-on-a-return-trip-in-spa (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Deepwater Black Trilogy by Ken Catran - Book Covers]

**[The Deepwater Trilogy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?187021)** by Ken Catran

Here's an overview:

> A virus breaks out and leaves the humans residing on Earth doomed.
> However, in a desperate attempt before the end, all humanity's
> resources are dedicated to a crash program to produce a deep space
> ark, capable of seeding humanity on a new world.

Reference to the "cloning" aspect...

> The ship is crewed by six clones; teenage versions of people who achieved great works during
> the ark project and equipped with the memories of their donors. Prior
> to its arrival, however, the crew is awoken prematurely to face a
> threat to the ship, before their memories are complete.

This section from another review describes other plot points:

> Each book in the trilogy is narrated by an Earth kid. The others are
> cloned from genes taken from Mars and Jupiter: Bren has green skin,
> Lis has blue hair! Rob, Denie and Connal all experience 'prexes', or
> pre-existences that their clone-ancestors had on twentieth-century
> Earth.

[image: Deepwater Black TV Show - Cast Pic]

The characters in the television show, called "**[Mission Genesis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118403/)**" in certain markets, were older than in the books (why does that not surprise me?). Some were given new names, some dropped and others were combined. For instance, the ship's navigation system (which you recalled correctly as COL) and NUN were merged into GEN.

Watch the show on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04raZVPk9q0).

*~ Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_trilogy), [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeepwaterBlack) and [Karen's Deepwater Page](http://webspace.webring.com/people/au/um_8151/d02kc.html)*

Comment: I remember this show, it had Ezri Dax on it (bottom left) and Harper from Andromeda (bleach blonde guy)... it wasn't half bad.  I hadn't realized it was a book series, I might check them out!

Comment: I read these books back when I was about 12, and couldn't put them down! They got me into reading for the longest time, and I wanted to track them down, but I couldn't remember the title for the life of me until I found this page, so thanks!