# A book about cloning, sentient ship and others

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

A few years ago I read a book and I am trying to find it again any help would be appreciated.

As I remember it was an older book where the protagonist gains consciousness on a space ship thats gained sentience (this may be where I'm wrong as I cannot remember if its sentient or just gone rogue), the crew has been cloned over many generations and have been perverted into almost monsters. The protagonist tries to fix the problem.

The book ends with the actual crew waking up and exiting the space craft which isn't in deep space but in a sea and they find evidence of what had happened.

Comment: I've marked your question as a duplicate. That's not a censure or an indication of a bad question. Instead, it's a bookkeeping measure to try to keep details in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be one of the [Deepwater Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_trilogy) books by Ken Catran. Each follows a teenager of the crew, which is comprised of teenagers cloned from great men of Earth. Indeed, the ship's navigation computer, COL, is sentient, and the reveal of the first book, *Deepwater Black*, is that they're underwater, not in space.

I found it by searching for *book spaceship clones actually in water*, which brought me to [Sci-fi book and TV series: teenage clones on a spaceship ark, remembering their original lives](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49469/)